# EventListenerYAMLError: mapping values are not allowed here in app.xml

Tags: google-app-engine

I created a simple GoogleAppEngine application.

```
application: foo
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /bar
   script: foo.application
```

When starting with **dev_appserver.py .** I get the following error:

```
EventListenerYAMLError: mapping values are not allowed here in app.xml
```

Comment: Check the indenting. script and url should be level.

Comment: what a terrible error message - dev_appserver should fail if the format of the yaml file is bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you Greg the indentation fixed it.

```
handlers:
- url: /bar
  script: foo.application
```